# SSMS Intellisense - Data Dictionary Incorporation - Show Object Descriptions in Popup?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, metadata, intellisense

Can anyone point me in the right direction for an SSMS intellisense replacement that will show the object descriptions in the popup?

This will help speed up onboarding as well as making myself familiar when dev hands me a new beast to manage.  Object names should always be fairly descriptive, but sometimes what made sense 10 years ago makes little now, and cross-referencing a dictionary doc is a productivity barrier.

Mockup example using AdventureWorks:

[image: Example using AdventureWorks]

Comment: This is a last resort: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166215(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Like "descriptions" set with extended properties?

Comment: Correct.  MS_Description to be exact: the same one available in the table designer for columns where I lifted the AdventureWorks one.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there is any way to fool SSMS into doing that (and if it isn't slow enough for you already, this isn't going to help). You might want to see if some of the popular add-ins (eg Red Gate SQL Prompt) will handle this... and if not, file a feature request. As unpopular as extended properties are, 3rd party tool vendors are far more likely to add this functionality than Microsoft. That said, you might check if SQL Server Data Tools provides a better experience here. I doubt it but I don't use it...

Comment: Thanks for the input... I will definitely make a feature request for SSDT since I see them eventually absorbing SSMS after the SQL 2012 VS merger.  I just checked and it has the same behavior.  I can get Red Gate/Apex/etc in my budget but I doubt all of the dev, qa, and ba teams can.

Answer (score 0):

Using native tools there's no way to do this.  You could try checking with RedGate or SSMS Tool Pack and see if either team would be able to assist you.

Comment: I wish I could take that negative vote away because the SSMS Tool Pack team seems like they would enjoy a challenge like this.  Thanks for mentioning it; I've never used it before and like the tools it already offers.